# how to map snps to ref gene file

Tags: linux, text-processing, bioinformatics

I have the following data set about the snps ID

```
  POS ID    
    78599583    rs987435
    33395779    rs345783
    189807684   rs955894
    33907909    rs6088791
    75664046    rs11180435
    218890658   rs17571465
    127630276   rs17011450
    90919465    rs6919430
```

and a gene reference file

```
genename    name    chrom   strand  txstart txend
CDK1    NM_001786   chr10   +   62208217    62224616
CALB2   NM_001740   chr16   +   69950116    69981843
STK38   NM_007271   chr6    -   36569637    36623271
YWHAE   NM_006761   chr17   -   1194583 1250306
SYT1    NM_005639   chr12   +   77782579    78369919
ARHGAP22    NM_001347736    chr10   -   49452323    49534316
PRMT2   NM_001535   chr21   +   46879934    46909464
CELSR3  NM_001407   chr3    -   48648899    48675352
```

I'm trying to match the genes with the SNps location, so include the snps that has

POS >= txstart and POS<= txend

for example I want a data set that has the following columns

genename   SNPID   chrom   position   txstart   txend

Comment: Are you comparing line-by-line or the line pairs that have the same chrom?

Comment: I'm not sure but i can tell is that each gene might have more than on snpID. Basically discard the CHROM for the snp data and just compare the location and snp ID, so I guess it is line by line

Comment: @FloHe it is line by line

Comment: Are there actually any matches, in the example files you have given?

Comment: @steeldriver will you can find 1 or 2 matches the data file is large about 900 thousand  so there will be matches and each gene might have more than one snpID

Comment: @FloHe where is the output file ? the one that contain the data  after matching the 2 files and how to fix the error that i had mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, your sample files do not contain any matches of the kind you describe.

If we modify the first file to

```
CHROM  POS ID   
chr7    78599583    rs987435
chr15   33395779    rs345783
chr1    189807684   rs955894
chr20   33907909    rs6088791
chrx    1234567     rsMadeUp
chr12   75664046    rs11180435
chr1    218890658   rs17571465
chr4    127630276   rs17011450
chr6    90919465    rs6919430
```

such that the made-up entry falls in the range

```
genename    name    chrom   strand  txstart txend
CDK1    NM_001786   chr10   +   62208217    62224616
CALB2   NM_001740   chr16   +   69950116    69981843
STK38   NM_007271   chr6    -   36569637    36623271
YWHAE   NM_006761   chr17   -   1194583 1250306
SYT1    NM_005639   chr12   +   77782579    78369919
ARHGAP22    NM_001347736    chr10   -   49452323    49534316
PRMT2   NM_001535   chr21   +   46879934    46909464
CELSR3  NM_001407   chr3    -   48648899    48675352
```

then

```
awk '
    NR == FNR && FNR > 1 {snp[$2]=$3; next} 
    FNR > 1 {
      for (p in snp) {if (p>=$5 && p<=$6) print $1, snp[p], $3, p, $5, $6}
    }
  ' snpsid generef 
YWHAE rsMadeUp chr17 1234567 1194583 1250306
```

Comment: do you write the file snpsid as snpsid.txt ? same for generef

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk for this:

```
awk 'FNR==1 {next} FILENAME=="snipsid" {k++; POS[k]=$2; ID[k]=$2;} \
        FILENAME=="gene" {i++; if(POS[i]>=$5 && POS[i]<=$6) \
        print $1, ID[i], $3, POS[i], $5, $6} \
    ' snipsid gene >out_file
```

Comment: do I have to add .txt to file name?

Comment: it gave me this error    awk: FNR==1 {next} FILENAME=="pre_snpinfo_tumot.txt" {k++; POS[k]=$2; ID[k]=$2;} \  
awk:                                                                             ^ backslash not last character on line

Comment: where is the output file ? the one that contain the data  after matching the 2 files and how to fix the error that i had mentioned

Comment: @zx8754 can you help with this question please

Comment: Just had to remove the two blanks after the first \.